# WPF how to cut stackpanel content?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, stackpanel

I need to print some informations, and I have print preview page which contains:

```
<Grid Name="pageGrid" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="70">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="headerGrid" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Name="pageSummaryGrid" Margin="0" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Name="dataGrid" Margin="0" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Name="footerGrid" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

The header and footer exists on every page. pageSummaryGrid and dataGrid may be populated. Also I have this code which populate print details:

```
pageCount = pages.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
{
    myPage = new PrintPreviewPage();
    header = new PrintPageHeader();
    footer = new PrintPageFooter();

    CreateHeaderAndFooter(i + 1, pageCount, header, footer);
    myPage.SetHeader(header);
    myPage.SetTableData(pages[i]);
    myPage.SetFooter(footer);

    pageList.Add(myPage);
}
```

Methods:

```
public void SetTableData(Panel panel)
{
    dataGridGrid.Children.Add(panel);
}

public void SetHeader(FrameworkElement header)
{
    headerGrid.Children.Add(header);
}

public void SetFooter(FrameworkElement footer)
{
    footerGrid.Children.Add(footer);
}
```

pages is list of StackPanel(represent print details, for example some pictures,list etc.) When some pages[i] is larger than real page height then the footer becomes invisible and print details(list,pictures etc.) is cutted(footer is pushed).

I want that footer is always visible, and if I need to cut just print details. I tried to set MaxHeight, Height, ActualHeight and ClipToBounds properties of StackPanel, but nothing works. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to put stack panel in scroll viewer?

Comment: Scroll viewer is not a option, because this is a print preview .

Comment: Why not set Max height for dataGrid, pageSummaryGrid and then see if footer shows up. change Auto to * and then use Visibility property of both to make them visible or collpased as per required

Comment: MaxHeight is good idea, I resolved this similiary - with setting pages[i].MaxHeight

Comment: Second code example which I set here contains some additional code( myPage .Measure(...), myPage.UpdateLayout() etc.) and setting pages[i].MaxHeight after this method calls didn't work(i set after because Height and Width properties is available after this methods execution). Of course I tried to "update" myPage, grid which contains that panels but that didn't work.

Comment: Putting the pages in a StackPanel will cause this issue b/c a StackPanel never has any idea of external boundaries.  A Grid does.  Can you swap out your Stackpanel for a Grid and see if that works?